# Getting currently selected listview item spinner on button click

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner, custom-adapter

I am creating an app that contains a functionality that includes a list of questions with multiple answer options for each. To do this I am using a listview that with each item contains a TextView for displaying the question with a spinner that holds the list of answers. I am attempting to retrieve the currently selected value of a spinner within each listview item. This is typically easy except for the fact that I have a spinner for each listview item and the number of spinners I need is "unknown" until the number of questions is loaded.

My issue is how to get the value of each currently selected spinner item. Currently I am only able to get the value of the first spinner item. Below is my code for the class that uses my custom adapter:

```
questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    masterAnswersList = new ArrayList<>();
    //For all questions with the tech answer's group id, get questions
    for(int k = 0; k < allQuestions.size(); k++) {
        final int z = k;
        //Each question for the tech
        System.out.println("Question " + z + " " + allQuestions.get(z).getQuestionTitle());
        questionsList.add(new CompleteQuestions.ListViewItem() {{
            QUESTION = allQuestions.get(z).getQuestionTitle();
        }});

        int questionId = allQuestions.get(z).getQuestionId();
        //Get all possible answers for this question based on the question and the group id
        allAnswers = db.getAllGroupAnswers(questionId, groupID, database);
        answersList = new ArrayList<>();
        //For all answers for this question, add to arraylist
        for(int j = 0; j < allAnswers.size(); j++) {
            final int p = j;
            answersList.add(new CompleteQuestions.ListViewItem() {{
                ANSWER = allAnswers.get(p).getAnswerTitle().trim();
            }});
        }
        masterAnswersList.add(answersList);
    }
    adapter = new CompQuestionsAdapter(this, questionsList, masterAnswersList);
    completeQuestionsListView.setAdapter(adapter);


//For the number of items in the listview
                for (int i = 0; i < completeQuestionsListView.getCount(); i++) {
                    //Update ticket questions table
                    String techChoice = CompQuestionsAdapter.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    System.out.println("techChoice: " + techChoice);
                    //Get id of answer tech chose
                    int techAnswerId = db.getAnswerId(techChoice, database);
                    int questionId = allQuestions.get(i).getQuestionId();
                    int groupId = db.getGroupId(techChoice, questionId, database);
                    System.out.println("Group id: " + groupId);
                    Ticket questionTicket = new Ticket(questionId, techAnswerId, ticketId, companyId, groupId, true);
                    db.addTicketQuestionResponse(questionTicket, context, database);
                }
```

And part of the custom adapter itself:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /**
     * The database used to pull all ticket information
     */
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    final SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();

    ListViewItem item = questions.get(position);
    //ListViewItem item2 = answers.get(position).get(position);
    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_questions_view, null);

    TextView question = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.QUESTION);
    question.setText("" + item.QUESTION);

    spinner = (Spinner)vi.findViewById(R.id.ANSWERS);
    List<String> strAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<CompleteQuestions.ListViewItem> currentAnswers = answers.get(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < currentAnswers.size(); i++) {
        strAnswers.add(currentAnswers.get(i).ANSWER);
    }
    //Place all the cleared by codes in a string array used to populate the spinner
    String[] strArrayAnswers = new String[strAnswers.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < strAnswers.size(); i++) {
        if(strAnswers.get(i) != null) {
            strArrayAnswers[i] = strAnswers.get(i);
        }
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strArrayAnswers);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    List<String> selections = new ArrayList<>();
    selections.add(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    System.out.println("Currently selected item: " + spinner.getSelectedItem());

    return vi;
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to define an interface so your adapter class can use to tell the parent class which item has been chosen from the spinner in **position** and what is the **selectedItem**

**The OnSpinnerItemSelected Interface**

```
public interface OnSpinnerItemSelected {
    void onItemSelected(int position, String selectedItem);
}
```

Then you need to pass one OnSpinnerItemSelected Object in your adapter constructor.

```
private OnSpinnerItemSelected onSpinnerItemSelected;

public CompQuestionsAdapter(......, OnSpinnerItemSelected onSpinnerItemSelected) {
    this.onSpinnerItemSelected = onSpinnerItemSelected;
}
```

In your class that uses custem adapter add this:

```
    adapter = new CompQuestionsAdapter(this, questionsList, masterAnswersList, new OnSpinnerItemSelected() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int position, String selectedItem) {

        }
    });
```

In your adapter call onItemSelected method (in getView method)

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            onSpinnerItemSelected.onItemSelected(position, adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Just let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: I do have a question: how can this be called within the onClickListener called when a button is pressed?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thank you so much, I spent far too much time on this!

Comment: I know this is a different question, but if possible would you be able to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427659/saving-individual-currently-selected-spinner-item-in-expandablelistview-child? If not that's fine, but it is a somewhat similar topic.